# Boot from USB RAID1 in Raspberry Pi 4 running Ubuntu 22.04 64bit

Tags: boot, raid, raspberrypi, 22.04

The Raspberry Pi 4 8GB I received today boots without any modification from USB and can run Ubuntu 22.04 64Bit pre-installed for arm.

My idea was to have two USB drives RAID1 in the USB3 ports with mdadm and boot from there.
Is there an installation disk for Arm as it exists for Intel processors?

If I boot from a third USB disk with pre-installed Ubuntu 22.04 how can I format, assemble, and transfer Ubuntu installation to the RAID1 partition?

What special needs should I include in order to boot from a raid1 partition?
Thank you in advance

Comment: It is doable. You must install all needed drivers in initial ramdisk. But raid works slower than single disk, because usb3 ports are connected to the same usb controller.

Comment: I am aware that this is slower that single disk. The reason for this solution is the simplicity in case of a disk failure. You just remove the failed disk, insert a new and do the replacement from a shell remotely, even without restart

Comment: Did you solve it? How did you do?